# Can I get the delivery time of sent emails via Activity History?

Tags: email, reporting, activityhistory

In our custom object, our custom support team usually use the send an email button in the activity history section of a custom object to send out emails.

[image]

Last month, we have noticed several delays in the email delivery. So our business team is trying to get a report on it. My question is are we able to do so in Salesforce? If yes, how could we do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the emails are less than 30 days old, you could [request a log of sent emails](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_logs.htm&type=0) (Setup > Logs > Email Logs). Any report that you write will only show the time the email was originally requested to be sent, not when it actually left the mail servers. The email log, on the other hand, will show useful information like the number of retries and how long the email was queued. You can also filter by specific addresses, if you desire. You'll have to the actual analysis outside of Salesforce instead of running a report.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I guess one thing I need further to this one would be the related sobject Id for this. Otherwise it is still a little bit hard to tell.

Comment: @LanceShi You'd need to run your activity report, export it, then marry them up by subject/email/sender id or something. The email server doesn't seem to know about the related ID values directly, although you might also look at the Message ID, which I believe is correlated to the WhatId.

Comment: Thank you for that. I am thinking about a similar thing to utilise Excel's vlookup functionality to match these. I was thinking about whether there exists any original Salesforce way of achieving this but it doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce provides a standard OOTB report type called `HTML Email Status`, based on which you can build a report to display following information.

[image: HTML Email Status]

Date Sent - will display the timestamp of sending emails.

*By the way, this report doesn't cover text based emails*